# R: created a names vector containing the means of multiple numeric vectors

Tags: r, loops, variables, vector

I have over 20 numeric vectors which consist of a series of values. each vector is distinguished by a letter, e.g. val_a, val_b, val_c etc...

I would like to put the means from each of these vectors into a single named vector. I could of course do this in a laborious manner like so:

```
obs <- c("val_a" = round(mean(val_a),3),
         "val_b" = round(mean(val_b),3),
         "val_c" = round(mean(val_c),3))
```

But with 20 vectors this then becomes tedious to write out, and not to mention an inelegant solution. How can I create the named vector in a more succinct way? I have made an attempt using a for loop, as so:

```
obs <- c(for (j in 1:20) {
  assign(paste("val",letters[j], sep = "_"), 
  mean(as.name(paste('val',letters[j], sep = '_'))),)
})
```

In the right hand argument passed to assign, "as.name" is used in order to remove the quotation marks from output of "paste". So the second argument passed to assign returns a character which has the exact same name as the numeric vector that I want get the mean of, e.g. val_a. But I get the error messsage:

Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(as.name(paste("val", letters[j], sep = "_"))) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: try the `get` function: `get('val_a')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

To build on [bouncyball](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5619526/bouncyball)'s comment so you have a full answer, you can do this:

```
sapply(paste('val', letters[1:20], sep='_'), function(x) round(mean(get(x)), 3))
```

#### Explanation

For an object in your environment called `x`, `get("x")` will return `x`. See `help("get")`. Then we can do this for every element of `paste('val', letters[1:20], sep='_')` using `sapply()`, or if you like, a loop.

#### Example

```
val_a <- rnorm(100)
val_b <- rnorm(100)
val_c <- rnorm(100)

sapply(paste('val', letters[1:3], sep='_'), function(x) round(mean(get(x)), 3))

      val_a       val_b       val_c 
-0.09328504 -0.15632654 -0.09759111
```